# Python Console and Python Virtual Machine how do work?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know if when Python 3 is executed in interactive mode, the code that is written on console is translated in bytecode.
For example:

On terminal, after started python in interactive mode

```
>>> x = 10 #is translated in bytecode?
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: `REPL` = Read, Eval, Print, Loop. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Comment: thanks for your answer but is not the answer that I'm looking for. I asked if the Python REPL translate the code in bytecode, before execute it.

Comment: There is literally no other way a piece of python code can be executed, except for being translated to bytecode and then executed by the Python virtual machine